# Wordpress: get one record that meets certain rules

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, posts

Friends, I ask for help in an unusual task.

Wordpress and a custom post type `events`. Events have several ACF fields: `e_date` (event date), `e_active` (true/false field - real event) and `e_forecast` (true/false field - event forecast). When filling in an event, `e_date` (a required field) is filled in and `e_active` or `e_forecast` is set, depending on the type of event. So, I need to get all the event records, check these records for compliance with certain rules and output one last record. The rules are as follows:

1. Check all entries with `e_active` by date. I.e. compare `e_date` with the current date. If there is an `e_active` event and with an `e_date` that has not yet occurred, then we output it.
2. If all `e_active` with `e_date` have passed, i.e. they do not correspond to point 1, then we check `e_forecast` and `e_date` according to the same principle.
3. If 1 and 2 don't fit, then just `else {}`

At the moment, I get 1 last published record, but often `e_forecast` is published later than `e_active`, although `e_active` has not yet reached `e_date`.

```
$events = get_posts([
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'numberposts'       => 1,
    'meta_query'        => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key'       => 'e_active',
            'value'     => true
        ],
        [
            'key'       => 'e_forecast',
            'value'     => true
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Unfortunately, I myself can't even imagine how to sort through, say, the last 10 records for compliance with the described rules. I really hope your help)